# How to properly open a 12-bit tiff file to use in a QApplication

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, tiff, qapplication

Context:  I am creating an application to view a stream of images using PyQt5. I am opening either jpg images or 12-bit tiff images, depending on the folder chosen. These images are converted into numpy arrays, and then into QImages and QPixmaps.

So far, I am perfectly able to open the jpg images (which are all in RGB), but am having difficulty properly displaying the tiff images. These images are 12-bit, single channel images (so, only RED light, or only GREEN light, etc). The code I use to load images is below (where newImage is the path to the image file):

```
img_arr = np.asarray(Image.open(newImage))
if newImage.split(".")[-1] in ["png", "jpg"]:
    self.background_pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(img_arr.data, img_arr.shape[1],
                                               img_arr.shape[0], img_arr.strides[0],
                                               QImage.Format_RGB888))
else:
    self.background_pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(img_arr.data, img_arr.shape[1],
                                                   img_arr.shape[0], img_arr.strides[0],
                                                   QImage.Format_RGB444).convertToFormat(QImage.Format_Grayscale16))
```

The class this QPixmap is in is a QGraphicsView. I'll include all code needed to reproduce this at the end of the post. The photo, when printed out in its numpy array state, looks like this:

```
array([[1004,  942, 1159, ..., 1036,  989,  911],
       [1074, 1046,  982, ...,  951, 1047, 1056],
       [1080, 1174, 1129, ..., 1078, 1124, 1101],
       ...,
       [1400, 1346, 1261, ..., 1367, 1547, 1367],
       [1297, 1184, 1339, ..., 1362, 1295, 1506],
       [1373, 1440, 1370, ..., 1334, 1429, 1487]], dtype=uint16)
```

The tiff images are displayed using the code in the `else` statement. This current version (the RGB444 + Grayscale16) is the closest I have gotten to properly displaying the image, but it is still incredibly grainy.

I have attempted all sorts of combinations from the QImage format table, but nothing seems to work correctly. Below are links to what the image should look like, and what I actually get.

Good Picture:

[image: Original image opened with windows image viewer]

Bad Picture:

[image: Image that appears when loaded in my application]

Basically, I am wondering if anyone knows what type of format would be best to properly show this type of image? I need it to be as clear as possible, since it will be used for hardware testing.

So now obviously there is a lot more code to my software than just this, but I do believe you can replicate what I am doing with the code below. This program is based off of another PyQt5 program I was shown by a fellow programmer, so if anything is odd or not standard, that is most likely why. I've never worked with PyQt5 before this, so I'm completely new to the standard way of setting things up, and most of what I have written is from what I've found on the internet.

```py
class ImageViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, pixmap=None):
        super(ImageViewer, self).__init__(parent, pixmap)
        
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.addPixmap(pixmap)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.parent = parent

    def change_pixmap(self, event):
        self.scene.clear()
        self.scene.addPixmap(pixmap)
        self.scene.addPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.parent.image))

    def updateImage(self, newImage):
        img_arr = np.asarray(Image.open(newImage))
        if newImage.split(".")[-1] in ["png", "jpg"]:
            self.background_pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(img_arr.data, img_arr.shape[1],
                                                   img_arr.shape[0], img_arr.strides[0],
                                                   QImage.Format_RGB888))
        else:
            self.background_pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(img_arr.data, img_arr.shape[1],
                                                       img_arr.shape[0], img_arr.strides[0],
                                                       QImage.Format_RGB444).convertToFormat(QImage.Format_Grayscale16))

        self.image = QImage(self.background_pixmap.size(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
        self.change_pixmap(self.background_pixmap)

class ImageTester(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super(ImageTester, self).__init__()
        # Main Window Set up
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.resize(1000, 800)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.centralHLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.centralHLayout.setObjectName("centralHLayout")

        # Image Viewer Setup
        self.imageViewer = ImageViewer(self, image)
        self.imageViewer.setGeometry(image.rect())
        self.imageViewer.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
        self.imageViewer.setObjectName("imageViewer")
    
        self.centralHLayout.addWidget(self.imageViewer)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

    def changeImage(self, newImage):
        self.imageViewer.updateImage(newImage)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Main Window
    window = ImageTester(sys.argv[1])
    window.show()  

    # Start app
    return sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit:
I have attempted to load the image as just, `self.background_pixmap = QPixmap(newImage)`, but it just loads the file as all white. So that does not work either.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to numpy if Qt can directly read the TIFF format as the docs point out: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html?

Comment: Also it would be great if you share some .tiff images to be able to test your code

Comment: @eyllanesc I'll give it a try, but I'm pretty sure I remember the person's whose code this is based on saying that the Qt functions weren't able to convert the image properly, and that's why the numpy array was used. Although they were more so reading the meta data, rather than displaying the image...  How would I go about doing that? I do not have the reputation needed for most of the image stuff on here, plus the tiff files are larger than 2Mb so stackoverflow won't let them be uploaded directly...

Comment: 1) QPixmap can upload images directly (the same happens for png and jpg):  `self.background_pixmap = QPixmap(newImage)`, 2) You could upload the image to drive, dropbox, etc and share the link through a comment

Comment: Woops, guess I was thinking too in the box for sharing an image. Here is a link to one of the tiff photos:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i5sMajGPthu5hcslVzwHyoYl55wqI5Uk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your link does not allow me to access, you must make it public

Comment: There we go, now it should be public @eyllanesc Sorry about that